r.fill.dir not responding
I have been working on delineation of the Orange river basin in South Africa. Its now one full week trying to fill the DEM file using r.fill.dir in QGIS but it take decades with no response and the process just hung.
I need help, either someone sharing with me the filled-DEM or issuing other best way to go about.
The DEM file can be found in https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/591f6d02e4b0ac16dbdde1c7 under zip file name (af_dem_5_2.zip)

I randomly downloaded dem_7 and ran it through ArcPro, worked fine for me, filled>flow direction>Flow accumulation. all processed < 3 mins. Certainly not 1 week!

I dont understand the issue with the plagins in QGIS:

Sadly, I have never had much luck with any of the GRASS tools in QGIS so I can't tell you what's up with that particular. However, I can point you to an alternative (and free) toolset that also has a QGIS plugin with the tools you need.
I would suggest looking into WhiteBoxTools Open Core (https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/). Whitebox offers a free software with 400+ GIS and remote sensing tools, including multiple DEM filling tools. It comes with a Python and R API if you are a scripter, a QGIS and ArcGIS Pro plugin, and its own GUI if you want to do things outside of other software environments. If you regularly do any kind of GIS or remote sensing work, it's a great piece of software to add to your toolset anyway.
